# getClass().getName() doesn't return class name in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**LOGCAT fragment**

```
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"albumList: " + 
albumsList.get(position).getAlbum());
```

**OUTPUT**:

`D/c.c.a.f.a: albumList: test`

My fragment is named albumFragment but why does `getClass().getName()` return `c.c.a.f.a`

I already tried changing `getName()` to `getCanonicalName()` and `getSimpleName()` but these also don't work.

Comment: Do you use some kind of code obfuscator or minimizer?

Comment: Just to make sure: the out put "D/c.c.a.f.a" not from log4j right?

Comment: yes im using shrinkResources and minify, but when i try logging in an activity it does show the class name?

Comment: @NghiaDo No it's not

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was i was using an **obfuscator** and solved it by setting `minifyEnabled` to **false**.

```
debug {
         debuggable true
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```